# svg element in pseudo content does not appear

Tags: google-chrome, svg, pseudo-element

This problem has occurred in chrome version 51.0.2704.84.

```
.svg a:before {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 26px;
    height: 26px;
    content: url("link.svg");
}
```

here is sample code.

[Reproduction page](https://webnobushi.github.io/svgbug/)

[Sample code](https://github.com/webnobushi/svgbug/tree/master/dist)

Please tell me if there is a mistake .

Work around: use the background url property,This problem could be avoided.

Comment: I have the same problem. The code is ok but chrome doesnt display the pseudo content. When you scale the windows or make zoom, the icons appear again...

Comment: Yes. It will be displayed by trigger of re-rendering. This behavior is chrome bug?

Comment: The pseudo-element `:before` generated content is now displaying in `Chrome 56` .. tested on `Windows 10` and `Windows 7` .. looks like Chrome Dev's fixed it.